# What does `contrib` mean in the name of a grunt package?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm pretty sure that it means contribution, but I'm not sure significance that's supposed to convey. I'm torn between:

- It was contributed by the open source community and has no affilition with grunt
- It was contributed by, and is directly affiliated with grunt

Which is it? Or is it something completely different? Sorry if there's an FAQ for this which I wasn't able to find when searching.

Comment: [Officially maintained "contrib" plugins are marked with a star  icon.](http://gruntjs.com/plugins).

Comment: There are some miscellaneous packages with 'contrib' in the title, but the majority of the most popular `contrib` packages are maintained by the grunt team.